# How to merge data using php

Tags: php, arrays, merge, explode

Currently my MySQL data stored like below

```
product             | total
------------------------------------------
puma,adidas         | 100.00,125.00     
puma                | 80.00
reebok,adidas,puma  | 70.00,100.00,125.00
adidas,umbro        | 125.00,56.00
```

How to combine, explode, merge and total it like this in php?

```
puma     485.00
adidas   350.00
reebook  70.00
umbro    56.00
```

Comment: i recommend to look into database normalization and redesign your tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your result set looks like, but the logic should be the same:

```
$combined = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $productsArr = split(",", $result['product']);
    $totalsArr = split(",", $result['total']);

    // we'll assume both arrays are always the same size
    $prodCount = count($productsArr);
    for($i = 0; $i < $prodCount; $i++) {
        $combined[$productsArr[$i]] += (float)$totalsArr[$i];
    }
}
print_r($combined);
```

Comment: Dude, you'll get arrested for doing that.

Comment: for the first time will `$combined[$productsArr[$i]]` not give undefined warning/notice ?

Comment: `$i < $count;` should be `$i < $prodCount;`

Comment: I almost feel bad for posting this now.

Answer (score 2):

I have a quick question about your data structure: *Why the heck is your data structure like that???*

That being said, look to normalize your data (avoid duplicate data), create line items that belong to orders, a products table, etc...

```
products
--------
id
name
price


orders
------
id
created


order_items
------------
id
order_id
product_id
quantity
```

Now I can do queries like *give me the top 5 largest totals in orders*. *What's the most popular item I sell?* 
*Let me change the name of this product but not have my entire data fall apart.*

Comment: yes.. normally like that my db structure.. this part is for sales report. I want to keep the name of products although the product was deleted.